# Allow me to reorder favorite tags

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

I use favorite tags for two goals:

1. **Highlighting interesting questions**, and helping the system give me interesting questions.
2. **Convenient shortcuts to lists of questions**, where I might be able to help someone.

I would love to have all the tags I use for "2" grouped together, preferably at the top. However, I can not *conveniently* reorder my favorite tags. It seems favorite tags are (perhaps explicitly, not sure) shown in the order I added them.

It would be an improvement in my opinion if either:

1. Favorite tags could be reordered manually.
2. Favorite tags would be ordered (*e.g.* alphabetically).

Or, perhaps someone else has an even better suggestion?

PS. I've [searched](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfavorite-tags%5D+order), and carefully reviewed suggested potential duplicates and "Similar Questions", and did not find anything related so far.

Comment: Second this for Careers too. I tried to rearrange my favourite tags the other day and had to delete them all and re-add them.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR With Careers it's *slightly* better, because all tags sit in one big text box: I copy-paste the entire thing to a text editor, rearrange there, and copy it back to Careers. I guess that would even be an acceptable workaround on SO too since I don't reorder all that often...

Comment: We need this badly. I like to group my tags by technology/language and every time I add a new tag I have to delete and then re-add old tags to get them in the order I desire.

Comment: Has there been any update on this? Just a simple "send to top" would be great.

Comment: Any advance in this thread? I approve of this idea.