# Have "Favorite Tags" always been alphabetized?

Tags: discussion, tag-watching

Maybe I bumped my head and haven't noticed for the past few years but when did the Favorite Tags start sorting alphabetically?

I am almost positive that I used to have [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery), and then [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex).

[image: Screenshot of favorite tags in this order: jquery, php, regex.]

---

*Please don't judge my Favorite Tags; I am a glutton for punishment*

Comment: No, they were NOT sorted alphabetically, or even by popularity.  They used to be sorted by the order in which you added them to your list. I liked that, it meant I could have my most visited tags at the of the list, and my least visited tags at the bottom. But since a few minutes ago, they are now being sorted alphabetically, and I DO NOT like that.

Comment: I just wandered into Meta curious if this had changed recently, as I previously had PHP before MySQL and just noticed they had swapped. I had clicked what I thought was normally the MySQL tag and was utterly confused for a moment.

Comment: Was just about to ask this question, as mine we rearranged as well.  I assume it's now alphabetical.

Comment: @JacobG. yes, they are now being sorted alphabetical.

Comment: Mine, as well, must be new

Comment: You can now order them yourself with drag and drop ... oh wait ...no, that doesn't hold .... well, in 6 to 8 weeks probably ...

Comment: Maybe someone on Reddit complained about the sorting order?

Comment: Maybe they found the order unwelcoming...

Comment: @cteski Same here except I was greeted by jQuery; *sad trombone sound* `:-(`

Comment: I will gladly drop the jQuery tag from my list rather than re-train my muscle memory...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Yeah, same. I almost clicked on _JaVaSCripT_

Comment: @Don'tPanic That tears it! `jquery` has been dropped.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Just kidding, I have it myself.

Comment: Strictly-speaking, this used to be sorted based on the row ID of the table used to store them - which effectively worked as "in order added" unless a row was re-used. The change was made for consistency in the latter case; asking around for more details.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261406/drag-and-drop-feature-for-re-arranging-favorite-tags and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305363/allow-me-to-reorder-favorite-tags?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Shog9 Consistency with what? The related tags are sorted by popularity, question tags are sorted by popularity, but favorite tags are blazing a new trail by being alphabetized?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Perhaps that is a sign that the others will soon be alphabetized as well.

Comment: They've *never* been sorted by popularity unless you added them in popularity order, @MonkeyZeus. The goal here is consistency within the tag preference UI itself: a tag should always appear in the same place when favorited / ignored, even if it was previously favorited/ignored. Alphabetical is a simple way to achieve that, but it's not the only way - we could, for example, sort by creation date and thus *explicitly* maintain the behavior that was accidental before.

Comment: @Shog9 I understand the row ID concept and the accidental sorting. I'm just saying that "fixing" it by making it alphabetical instead of popularity-based was an interesting decision since everything else is popularity-based. I like the creation date solution the best, though.

Comment: Please put them back as they was :/ ... now I am clicking on wrong tags and I may miss questions because am notice this ...

Comment: This issue would make a fine Userscript where we can drag and sort them at will.

Comment: Please let us have the chronlogical tag view back. At least as a choice. Besides that, there is far, far to much space between the tags.

Comment: Why not add a simple plaintext link to allow changing the sorting on-the-fly - two options would've been enough and they can easily fit under the **Favorite tags** heading

Comment: Ironically, alphabetized tags was a long-wanted feature request on Meta Stack Exchange. (see [*Sort Favourite Tags on the sidebar in alphabetical order*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110224/351462))

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Please re-enable native custom tag sorting in some capacity or another.

I think [XKCD 1172](https://xkcd.com/1172/) is most relevant here.

[image: XKCD 1172: Workflow]

Comment: Well, except for the part where being able to organize your tags is not "horrifying."

Comment: This change definitely broke my workflow

Comment: Time to delete all of my favorite tags alphabetically before python so it goes back to the top of the list...

Answer (score 30):

Strictly-speaking, they were ordered by the ID of TagSetRow, the table used to store them internally, which would *usually* match the order in which you added them.

Of course, this was predicated on the corresponding TagSetRow being deleted if you removed a tag, which *used to be* a good bet but isn't anymore.

We're currently working on porting the redesigned tag-watching features that we've built for Teams back into the public Q&A sites. This redesign features a number of new features and a streamlined UI (no more hidden "ignore" function, no more having to visit your profile page to change how ignored tags work!). The public version of this UI hasn't changed yet (beyond the sorting), but the plumbing is in place now.

And that plumbing is important for what is yet to come: the ability to modify notification settings from the same UI. Again, without having to visit the profile page.

Not that any of this helps you... You were relying on a behavior that, while never really intended, was still useful. And now that's gone, and can't really come back without breaking again in a few weeks.

Long-term, we're working on an actual feature for this: saved question views, essentially the successor to the now-defunct New Nav project. But, that's long-term; again, it doesn't help you today.

### A solution, of a sort

So after brooding on this for a while, I threw together a userscript: [Reorderable Favorite Tags](https://stackapps.com/questions/8030/reorderable-favorite-tags-drag-drop-ordering-for-the-watched-tag-sidebar) (now on Stack Apps).

This'll restore the previous behavior: tags will remain in the order in which you add them.

But it'll even do one better: per rene's suggestion from the comments, it'll also allow you to reorder the tags *at will* by dragging them around (you have to start editing them first though, so as to avoid inadvertently reordering them while trying to click).

[image: demo]

Comment: Your userscript is great and all but why can't `order by create_date` be implemented or revert back to the ID of TagSetRow until the redesigned tag-watching features are complete?

Comment: There seem to be no sync between computers in your userscript, does it? The native SO tag selector had this before

Comment: How do I use such a user script? Have never seen one before.

Comment: Simple answer is a browser extension called "Tampermonkey", @Rudy - find the version for your browser of choice, install it, click the link to the script and it'll prompt you to install.

Comment: I suppose that could be added, @Ferrybig.

Comment: Because it would break again in a week, @Monkey.

Comment: @Shog9: Tried it now. Works great. Thanks again.

Comment: FWIW, Tampermonkey has [a restrictive EULA](http://tampermonkey.net/eula.php) where it's not even clear if you're allowed to use it non-commercially to develop scripts to share with others, and where I'm probably not allowed to use it on my work laptop. I'd like to see this working in [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/), but no luck so far. Will check over the weekend if I'm just trying it wrong, and if not, if small tweaking can make it work.

Comment: The only problem with Greasemonkey appears to be the "don't bother running this if this isn't a scripted SE page" check: Greasemonkey runs the userscript early, so `typeof StackExchange === "undefined"` because it simply hasn't been set yet. If I remove that check, it actually works already.

Comment: Should be corrected now @hvd

Answer (score 12):

The simple answer is no, they have not always been sorted alphabetically and the change appears to have gone through this week (or even today; I can't remember).  Previously, the tags were in the order that you added them to your favorites.

Personally, I would prefer being able to list them how I want to in a custom order, or the previous method of order-added (which is the same as the first ask, just more annoying to do).

Comment: yes it was today, I notice this when I missed few question by clicking on the CSS3 tag instead of CSS tag :/

Comment: It was definitely today.  I came in this morning and started answering questions while my tags were in the old sort order, and then saw them change order in between posting answers.